# Running Visual Studio without Admin Rights

Tags: windows, visual-studio

So we have a really unique situation where I work. We have thin clients that will have an extremely locked down VM running on them so that the user will not even be able to get to the C Drive. All files they will work with will be on another drive. The users will not have internet access or access to run things as Admin. However, I need to have them run Visual Studio, currently 2015, but that may change soon. At this point I am just working with 2015. Is there a way to allow Visual Studio to run properly (debugging websites, checking code into TFS, etc) with the command line or permissions?

As a note I am not a windows admin, but a developer tasked with getting this environment set up. Also as a note the VM will be Windows 10. All updates and installation will be run by a staff member who will have admin access as well.

Comment: What topics can I ask about here?  https://superuser.com/help/on-topic 
Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about … and it is _not_ about … _issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,_

Comment: Though, IT people coming here to get the answers for their environments is allowed generally. What we are guarding against with that rule is shadow IT.

Comment: That said, this question is very broad. VS is a large suite of applications and OP will need to define their needs within the application and test for proper function of each of them.

Comment: stanley, since it has been 5 months, did you manage to find a work around?  I am also trying to get VS in my laptop which I dont have admin rights, not sure what I can and cannot do yet.